# js-cookie Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "application/octet-stream"

Tags: js-cookie

I'm having this line in my document

`<script type="module" src="/js/js.cookie.mjs"></script>`

Everything works fine on my local server (i'm using nodejs), but when uploaded to the server, I can find this issue in the console :

**Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.**

Does anyone have a solution for me?

Edit: bump because no answer  :/